# Python 3.x - function args type-testing

Tags: python-3.x

I started learning Python 3.x some time ago and I wrote a very simple code which adds numbers or concatenates lists, tuples and dicts:

```
X = 'sth'
def adder(*vargs):
    if (len(vargs) == 0):
    print('No args given. Stopping...')
else:
    L = list(enumerate(vargs))
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        if (type(L[i][1]) != type(L[i + 1][1])):
            global X
            X = 'bad'
            break
    if (X == 'bad'):
        print('Args have different types. Stopping...')
    else:
        if type(L[0][1]) == int:                            #num
            temp = 0
            for i in range(len(L)):
                temp += L[i][1]
            print('Sum is equal to:', temp)
        elif type(L[0][1]) == list:                         #list
            A = []
            for i in range(len(L)):
                A += L[i][1]
            print('List made is:', A)
        elif type(L[0][1]) == tuple:                        #tuple
            A = []
            for i in range(len(L)):
                A += list(L[i][1])
            print('Tuple made is:', tuple(A))
        elif type(L[0][1]) == dict:                         #dict
            A = L[0][1]
            for i in range(len(L)):
                A.update(L[i][1])
            print('Dict made is:', A)

adder(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
adder([1,2,3,4], [2,3], [5,3,2,1])
adder((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (2,))
adder(dict(a = 2, b = 433), dict(c = 22, d = 2737))
```

My main issue with this is the way I am getting out of the function when args have different types with the 'X' global. I thought a while about it, but I can't see easier way of doing this (I can't simply put the else under for, because the results will be printed a few times; probably I'm messing something up with the continue and break usage).
I'm sure I'm missing an easy way to do this, but I can't get it.
Thank you for any replies. If you have any advice about any other code piece here, I would be very grateful for additional help. I probably have a lot of bad non-Pythonian habits coming from earlier C++ coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some changes I made that I think clean it up a bit and get rid of the need for the global variable.

```
def adder(*vargs):
    if len(vargs) == 0:
        return None # could raise ValueError

    mytype = type(vargs[0])
    if not all(type(x) == mytype for x in vargs):
        raise ValueError('Args have different types.')

    if mytype is int:
        print('Sum is equal to:', sum(vargs))
    elif mytype is list or mytype is tuple:
        out = []
        for item in vargs:
            out += item
        if mytype is list:
            print('List made is:', out)
        else:
            print('Tuple made is:', tuple(out))
    elif mytype is dict:
        out = {}
        for i in vargs:
            out.update(i)
        print('Dict made is:', out)

adder(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
adder([1,2,3,4], [2,3], [5,3,2,1])
adder((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (2,))
adder(dict(a = 2, b = 433), dict(c = 22, d = 2737))
```

I also made some other improvements that I think are a bit more 'pythonic'.  For instance

```
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

instead of

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
```

In a function like this if there are illegal arguments you would commonly short-cuircuit and just throw a ValueError.

```
if bad_condition:
    raise ValueError('Args have different types.')
```

Comment: The code looks way better now and the type-check var is outside the if, so there is no need for global.
Thanks for your answer, that was quick!

Comment: I made a couple more updates.  To get a sum of numbers in a list, you can just use the sum() function.  Also, check out my use of the all() function to check a condition for an entire array.  In this case I'm using it where you were checking that all the types match.

Answer (score 0):

Just for contrast, here is another version that feels more pythonic to me (reasonable people might disagree with me, which is OK by me).
The principal differences are that a) type clashes are left to the operator combining the arguments, b) no assumptions are made about the types of the arguments, and c) the result is returned instead of printed.  This allows combining different types in the cases where that makes sense (e.g, `combine({}, zip('abcde', range(5)))`).
The only assumption is that the operator used to combine the arguments is either `add` or a member function of the first argument's type named `update`.

I prefer this solution because it does minimal type checking, and uses duck-typing to allow valid but unexpected use cases.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

def combine(*args):
    if not args:
        return None
    out = type(args[0])()
    return reduce((getattr(out, 'update', None) and (lambda d, u: [d.update(u), d][1]))
                  or add, args, out)

print(combine(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
print(combine([1,2,3,4], [2,3], [5,3,2,1]))
print(combine((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (2,)))
print(combine(dict(a = 2, b = 433), dict(c = 22, d = 2737)))
print(combine({}, zip('abcde', range(5))))
```

Comment: The code errors if compiled in 3.x (needed to bracket prints).
The problem I have here is that when I use things like last combine call, the result is indeed unexpected, so I wonder if it isn't better to make sure that user gets out what he wants.  Is this the way of dealing with unexpected results when going with real applications?
This solution seems complicated for me atm, I not sure if I'm ready for advanced code like this, but thanks for your answer - that is something I will sure analyze carefully to understand.

Comment: Can't edit the previous comment anymore.
If I understand correctly, the first part of reduce deals with dict types -  the getattr checks if the type has method 'update', but can you please explain, what exactly lambda func does here? I don't fully understand how is the `[d.update(u), d][1]` working.

Comment: I've fixed the print lines (I added them late; the rest works correctly on python 3).  I'm not sure how the result of the last line is unexpected - the return type is the same as the type of the first argument, so the user is getting exactly what they asked for.  The principle I followed is that it is better to have only the minimum required conditions; this allows all valid uses, not just those that are forseen by the original author.

Comment: `update` returns `None`, but `reduce` needs a binary operator that returns a new computed value. `[d.update(u), d][1]` is an expression that executes `d.update(u)` and has a value of `d`.